# Copy RENDER OUTPUT (image result) to Windows clipboard?

Tags: image, uv-image-editor

How possible would it be to include a function in the Compositor, UV Editor and Image Editor that can "COPY TO CLIPBOARD" whatever image they have active?
The image editor "Copy to Clipboard" function is the one I'm most interested in, since I composite and do animated storyboards all the time.

It's too long of a hustle to do:
F12, Image>save as>target directory>type the name of the file> Switch application >file>open>target directory>image>ctrl+a> ctrl+c, switch application document tab, and finally ctrl+V just to layer the concept I am working in.

Image>copy Render Output to clipboard, switch application, CTRL+V seems speedier.

The "Edit externally" command already has this in mind, but the general idea with this new command is to assign a shortcut, use it in blender, switch applications, CTRL+V (even email windows would work best in this approach).

Please help me develop this as a simple addon for the Image Editor first. Thanks!
[image: copy to clipboard]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](https://popqjp.booth.pm/items/1686085) solution (windows only), but when i copy to clipboard render result with this addon (with alpha), i see image with black background in pasted image to Krita :( I can't find solution for this problem, but if you don't need in alpha-channel, this addon can help you.

Comment: I happen to know the author of this addon. Thank you. I will ask him why this problem occurs. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: The link leads to a very strange website, but not to the plugin.

Comment: It is a well-known site in Japan with high traffic ["Booth is a shop creation service linked with Pixiv](https://www.pixiv.help/hc/en-us/articles/235584668-What-is-BOOTH-). Some words about [Pixiv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixiv) in wiki. Personally, I am not afraid to download files from it. The addon can be downloaded by clicking on the big red button labeled "Free download (UseWin32ClipboardPackageV1p4.zip)". I am registered on this site and just checked - everything is downloading.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I found in doing the system clipboard with python: https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/

As for pasting images, I think the clipboard actually stores them as a URL like image://C:/Users/Jaywright/AppData/Local/.temp/save_here.png so you might try that in just the regular python IDE to start with.

Answer (score 0):

My usual workaround, if it helps you, is to maximize the image, print-screen or screen capture (there's usually an OS default, often PrtScrn), and copy from there. Hardly ideal, but for something like a sketch it does get the job done.